# unable to update in a database with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-update

I am unable to update my database. I have a table called Table2 and I have in it 3 columns: time, strike and vol. Please check the comments made in the line statements. thanks in advance for the help.

```
       VolLoc = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(VarianceLoc));

        Console.WriteLine("Local Volatility at strike " + strike1_run + " and time " + time0_run + " is: " + VolLoc + "\n");  // works perfectly at this point, I have a new value for my variable VolLoc

        string StrCmd1 = "UPDATE Table2 SET (vol = @vol_value) WHERE ((time = @T0_value)  AND (strike = @K1_value))"; // HERE is the problem, when I debug, the cursor steps on it normally but the database is not updated !!

        OleDbCommand Cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd1, MyConn);

        Cmd1.Parameters.Add("@vol_value", OleDbType.VarChar);
        Cmd1.Parameters["@vol_value"].Value = VolLoc.ToString();

        Cmd1.Parameters.Add("@T0_value", OleDbType.VarChar);
        Cmd1.Parameters["@T0_value"].Value = time0_run.ToString();

        Cmd1.Parameters.Add("@K1_value", OleDbType.VarChar);
        Cmd1.Parameters["@K1_value"].Value = strike1_run.ToString(); //the cursor steps on each of the line statements above, but the database is still not updated
```

Comment: Looks like you set it up ok.... but I don't see in the code where you execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the missing call to `ExecuteNonQuery` as stated by other, your code has another error that will show itself when your code will reach the ExecuteNonQuery method.

The word `TIME` is a reserved keyword in MS-Access Jet SQL.
You need to encapsulate it with square brackets `[time]`

So, summarizing

```
   string StrCmd1 = "UPDATE Table2 SET vol = @vol_value WHERE " + 
                    "([time] = @T0_value  AND strike = @K1_value)"; 

    OleDbCommand Cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd1, MyConn);
    .......
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, all the parameters are passed as string values. Are you sure that the corresponding fields are of the same datatype (text)

Comment: thanks a lot, it works now ! the time between brackets was the problem!

Comment: By the way, do we only execute the "cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();" with update?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is intended for every statement that INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE but also for every statement the manipulate the database in some way without returning a collection of rows (CREATE TABLE etc...). Instead ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar are intended for statement that returns data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call an [Execute method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on your [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) object.

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
    Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: add this after all the code written above. This is the line that actually executes your query against the DB.

Comment: I cannot add it at the end of the code, it shows error in the writing: "only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" .... you are right I see that I don't execut the query, do you know how to execute the query?